# Why expo notifications not popping up when app is in background/ completely close?(android)

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, expo-notifications

I followed what the documentation said. I can receive and send notifications. The problem is the notifications didn't pop up (only sound) when my app was in background or totally close. The pop up works only when I open the app(foreground). The notification sound works fine when app in all states. I use expo push notification tool and my server to send the notifications.

What's wrong with my code here?

```
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
});

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }

    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      // Learn more about projectId:
      // https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#configure-projectid
      token = (
        await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
          projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
        })
      ).data;
      console.log(token);
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    return token;
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));
    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        // setNotification(notification);
        notificationRef.current = notification;
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        console.log("DATA", response?.notification.request.content.data);
      });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
```